# if else to create a new column by new categorial

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column in a table from another one, this new column is a categorization of time intervals.
I created a function to calculate the time intervals from the other column.
Below is the function and error:

```
def calc_interval(df):
    if (enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=1)]):
        return 'menos de um 1 ano'
    elif (enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']>1) &(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=2.5 )]):
        return 'entre 1 e 2.5 anos '
    elif (enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']>2.5) &(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=5 )]):
        return 'entre 2.5 e 5 anos '
    elif( enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']>5) &(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=10 )]):
        return 'entre 5 e 10 anos'
    elif enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[ (enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS'])>10]:
        return 'mais de 10 anos'
enq2020['INTERVAL_REL']=enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS'].apply(calc_interval,axis=1)
                     
          TypeError: calc_interval() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: that is not a problem with code, it means that you simply gave wrong arguments to function call. `calc_interval(my_data_frame)` will work but not `calc_interval(axis=somevalue)`

Comment: if you want to pass entire dataframe then `enq2020.apply(calc_interval,axis=1)`, if just want to pass series then `enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS'].apply(calc_interval)` as series dont reqire axis parameter. However I suggest you to check your conditional statements too as it seems you are trying to call dataframe wich is out of scope in function. If that is the case then pass your dataframe as an arguments follows `enq2020.apply(calc_interval,axis=1,args=[enq2020])` and in function definition as `def calc_interval(row,enq2020):`

Answer (score 0):

you method expects a dataframe and you are passing a series:

```
def calc_interval(df):
    if (enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=1)]):
        return 'menos de um 1 ano'
    elif (enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']>1) &(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=2.5 )]):
        return 'entre 1 e 2.5 anos '
    elif (enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']>2.5) &(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=5 )]):
        return 'entre 2.5 e 5 anos '
    elif( enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']>5) &(enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS']<=10 )]):
        return 'entre 5 e 10 anos'
    elif enq2020.TEMPO_REL_ANOS[ (enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS'])>10]:
        return 'mais de 10 anos'
enq2020['INTERVAL_REL']=enq2020.apply(calc_interval,axis=1)
```

if you plan to pass a series then you don't need to pass axis argument:

```
enq2020['INTERVAL_REL']=enq2020['TEMPO_REL_ANOS'].apply(calc_interval)
```